# Is it possible to change the Visual Studio Schema Compare diff tool?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, diff

When you click a row in the result set of a [Visual Studio's Schema Comparison](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145979/SQL-Server-Schema-Comparison-Tool-in-Visual-Studio), it shows a diff of the source vs. the target of the comparison. Is there any way to use a different diff tool for that comparison?

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on which Source Control type you are using. But very often there are option pages associated with the Source Control option

Tools->Options->Source Control.

For example, Subversion has a setting called Subversion User Tools under this menu, that allows you to specify an external diff tool.

If TFS, then there is a menu option called Visual Studio Team Foundation Server. On this property page, is a button called Configure User Tools...

Other source control systems have similar mechanisms

Comment: I'm referring to the diff tool within Visual Studio's Schema Comparison Tool, not to any source control system. I've included a link in the question to clarify.